# Salesforce Native IOS SDK can't refresh access token

Tags: ios, salesforce, salesforce-ios-sdk

I am currently using the Salesforce.com IOS SDK Version 3.0 to build a native application that connects to salesforce. This app will be used for external users, so it is pointed at communities.

I first started by creating a Native IOS SDK app and getting that working and talking to salesforce.

I then created a new community, created a community user, gave them the proper permissions and finished setting up the community.

Next I went into the Xcode Project, under supporting files to the application plist. I then edited the SFDCOAuthLoginHost to be set to the community URL.

Once that was completed I restarted the app, and was able to login to the community through the native SDK and things would work great until the app hit its session timeout. At this point I receive these errors.

```
ERROR|SFNetworkOperation|callDelegateDidFailWithError Session expired or invalid
ERROR|SFNetworkOperation|Session timeout encountered. Requeue  0.000000or retry later
ERROR|SFNetworkEngine|Ignore session timeout error callback as host URL changed, request URL is https://dev-patientsupport-dev.cs21.force.com/dev/services/apexrest/patientNotifications, login host is [cs21.salesforce.com]
```

Of course because it cannot get a new session all web callouts fail after this point.

I have searched everywhere and cannot find a solution to this problem. My guess is that because the request is being made to the community URL, but the refreshed session is being sent from cs21.salesforce.com so it is being ignored.  Thanks again for everyones time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix for this bug has been submitted as part of Mobile SDK 3.1.1 patch on GitHub, npm (forceios), and Cocoapods. Please see https://plus.google.com/105428096535342044035/posts/AkoVwL5Kdt3 for more details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may be caused by the refresh token having its instanceURL set to the wrong destination when using communities. This may be a bug in the SDK as it works fine on the web. Try changing the instanceURL of the credentials to be the same as the URL of the community to see if that helps.